# Binary Search Tree - search function return object (C++)

Tags: c++, search, binary-search-tree

```cpp
//Node.cpp

Node::Node(DataType Item):item(Item)
{
    lchild = 0;
    rchild = 0;
}

DataType Node::getItem()
{
    DataType anItem = item; 
    return anItem;
}

void Node::setItem( const DataType & data)
{
    item = data;
}

Node* Node::getLChild() const
{
    Node * p = lchild;
    return p;
}

void Node::setLChild(Node * p)
{
    lchild = p;
}

Node* Node::getRChild() const
{
    Node * p = rchild;
    return p;
}

void Node::setRChild(Node * p)
{
    rchild = p;
}

Node::~Node()
{
}

//BST.cpp

DataType * BST::Search(const string name)
{
    return Search(name, root);
}

DataType * BST::Search(const string name, Node * r)
{
    if(r != 0)
    {
        if (name.compare(r->getItem().getname()) == 0)
            return &(r->getItem());
        else
        {
            if (name.compare(r->getItem().getname()) < 0)
                return Search(name, r->getLChild());
            else
                return Search(name, r->getRChild());
        }
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}

//main.cpp

    MyClass mc1("Tree","This is a tree");
    MyClass mc2("Book","This is a book");
    MyClass mc3("Zoo","This is a zoo");

    BST tree;
    tree.Insert(mc1);
    tree.Insert(mc2);
    tree.Insert(mc3);

    MyClass * mc = tree.Search("Book");
    if (mc != NULL)
        cout << mc->getname() << endl;
```

The problem is at the MyClass object (mc) returned from Search function.

I trace into Search() and make sure "r->getItem()" get what I want.

anything wrong with "return &(r->getItem());" ?

Thanks!

++++++

I'm a little bit confused.. can I change to "DataType BST::Search(const string name)"
instead of "DataType * BST::Search(const string name)"....it seems that the compiler cannot pass.
the return NULL will have some problem...

but I try your method to change the DataType* Node::getIthem() 
it still have error....@@

Comment: what does `Node::getItem()` return?

Comment: if getItem() returns MyClass (not MyClass&), then "return &(r->getItem());" returns an address to a temporary object, which is destroyed at the time of accessing it.  Other returns should be blocked by the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am *guessing* that `Node::getItem()` returns a `DataType` by value:

```
DataType Node::getItem();
```

When you take the address of that return value, you are essentially taking the address of something that will immediately disappear (a temporary). I suspect that `Node` holds `DataType` objects internally, in which case `Node::getItem()` could return a pointer to one of these.

```
DataType* Node::getItem() { return &item; }
const DataType* Node::getItem() const { return &item; }
```

or return by reference:

```
DataType& Node::getItem() { return item; }
const DataType& Node::getItem() const { return item; }
```

Comment: his getItem function is coded to return a copy of the data by value.  The copy has to be removed as well, or he'll have the same issue.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem...
it looks like I'd better to clarify the issue of pointer....
I'm confused why can't I use copy by value?

Comment: @user1371541 you can use copy by value, but then you cannot assign the return value's address to a pointer or reference. You need a copy on the caller side. Think of the return value as a temporary that is then used to copy construct something else (although the most likely compiler optimizes away the copy, semantically there is a copy going on).

Answer (score 0):

`return &(r->getItem());` will return the memory adress to whatever `r->getItem()` returns, not the object itself.
If `r->getItem()` returns a pointer you will have to `return (r->getItem());`.

Comment: Unless of course r->getItem() returns a reference. Then he might be fine depending on how the map works.

Comment: but if I change "r->getItem()" it will come up with "error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'DataType' to 'DataType *' "   
Node.cpp is:
`DataType Node::getItem() const
    {
        DataType anItem = item; 
        return anItem;
    }`

Comment: @user1371541: "DataType Node::getItem() const", see juanchpanza's answer